# Delete else statement but requires else statment

Tags: java, eclipse

So basically I'm doing a java tutorial but in order to follow along I need to make a class file. Everything was already given to me but it gives me an error. The error is: Delete else statement or something along those lines. But when I delete it it tells me to put another else statement there.
The code is :     Is this a problem with eclipse or is there something wrong with the code?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
public class In {
    static InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
    // Read a String from the standard system input
    public static String getString() {
        try {
            return br.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }
    // Read a number as a String from the standard system input
    // and return the number
    public static Number getNumber() {
        String numberString = getString();
        try {
            numberString = numberString.trim().toUpperCase();
            return NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(numberString);
        } catch (Exception e)

        {
            // if any exception occurs, just return zero
            return new Integer(0);
        }
    }
    // Read an int from the standard system input
    public static int getInt() {
        return getNumber().intValue();
    }
    // Read a long from the standard system input
    public static long getLong() {
        return getNumber().longValue();
    }
    // Read a float from the standard system input
    public static float getFloat() {
        return getNumber().floatValue();
    }
    // Read a double from the standard system input
    public static double getDouble() {
        return getNumber().doubleValue();
    }
    // Read a char from the standard system input
    public static char getChar() {
        String s = getString();
        if (s.length() >= 1)
            return s.charAt(0);
        else
            return’\ n’;
    }
}
```

Comment: You also have problem with indentation. Consider focusing on that part first (this will let you see/prevent other possible problems).

Comment: Pretty sure it's a problem with the code.

Comment: @Pshemo is that what is causing the problem? Because this is just copy and pasted from the text book....

Comment: Indentation isn't causing the problem, but in the process of fixing the indentation you will think about the code, and the answer may become obvious.

Comment: @Liste1134 No, indentation is not source of your problem, but you should start with it because it will help you find cause of your real problem faster. If you are using Eclipse then select your code and use `Ctlr`+`I` or `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F` to make your code easily readable.

Comment: `return ’\n’;` <- this is your problem.  It should be `return '\n';`  I'm not sure what those characters are that you've got typed in there, but they aren't single-quotes as recognized by Java.

Comment: Also, when reporting or asking about errors, it's critical you provide *specific* information, not just like "something along those lines" without any line numbers etc. It's not reasonable to expect us to guess; make it easy for people to help. It looks like you're using funky characters--don't blindly cut and paste without knowing what you're cutting and pasting; strange things can happen.

Comment: @azurefrog Thanks i changed that and it worked, again i just copy and pasted it from the text book so i wasn't sure what was up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is actually causing the error here is that whatever messed up marks you have around \n are not apostrophes... I have no idea what they are. After rewriting the code exactly as you did, except with apostrophes (plus using curly braces in the if and else statements because I prefer it that way), there were no errors:

```
public static char getChar ()
{
    String s = getString();
    if (s.length() >= 1){
        return s.charAt(0);
    }else{
        return '\n';
    }
}
```

Please, in the future, make sure to use correct indentations in your questions to make it much easier for us to read.

Comment: This is the correct answer. (that is, it's exactly the answer I would have given... :) )

Comment: But the OP mentioned '\n', which *is* a **char**, the newline character to be precise.  Why do you recommend changing from **char**s to `String`s?

Comment: Ah, I apologize. I did not see that he was using an escaped character. I updated my response.